# MySQL - GROUP_CONCAT with two columns from different tables

Tags: mysql

I want to concatenate two columns from different tables in my current GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT MAX(unit.unit_pk) AS unit_pk,
       GROUP_CONCAT(unit_outcome.unit_outcome SEPARATOR '|') unit_outcomes,
       MAX(program_outcome.program_outcome) program_outcome,
       GROUP_CONCAT(unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk) unit_outcome_pks, 
       program_outcome.program_outcome_pk,
       program_outcome.program_outcome
FROM unit
INNER JOIN unit_unit_outcome_lookup
    ON unit_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_fk = unit.unit_pk
INNER JOIN unit_outcome
    ON unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk = unit_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_outcome_fk
INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup
    ON program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_outcome_fk = unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk
INNER JOIN program_outcome
    ON program_outcome.program_outcome_pk = program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup.program_outcome_fk
GROUP BY program_outcome_pk ORDER BY program_outcome.program_outcome ASC
```

so that

```
GROUP_CONCAT(unit_outcome.unit_outcome SEPARATOR '|') unit_outcomes
```

combines `unit.unit_code` **and** `unit_outcome.unit_outcome` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT`

I assume this can be done?

The result I'm looking for would be a string from the GROUP_CONCAT like "unit_code: unit_outcome"

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ca7a01eceec02dcb89f3c11659933f13)

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(unit.unit_code, '-', unit_outcome.unit_outcome) SEPARATOR '|')` (separator in CONCAT() may be altered - or use CONCAT_WS()).

Comment: @Akina Fantastic, works for me, do you want to put that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(unit.unit_code, '-', unit_outcome.unit_outcome) SEPARATOR '|')
```

You may use any other separator in CONCAT() instead of `'-'` which I have randomly used.

Also you may use CONCAT_WS() instead of CONCAT() - especially when more than 2 fields must be concatenated in one source record.